# Mobile web site automation

Tags: testing, testcomplete

Is there any options to test websites in device browsers by using Testcomplete? Testcomplete has opetions like virtual browser in desktop but i need to automate my websites in default browsers in real device.

Answer (score 0):

Web testing on real mobile devices isn't supported as of now, but you can [submit a feature request](http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete).